# How to fix AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: pandas, numpy, attributes, append, series

Hi I'm still learning pandas and numpy in python

I learn from e-learning that you could combine 2 series with append but when I tried it It give me error

```
students_classes = pd.Series({'Alice': 'Physics',
                   'Jack': 'Chemistry',
                   'Molly': 'English',
                   'Sam': 'History'})
students_classes

kelly_classes = pd.Series(['Philosophy', 'Arts', 'Math'], index=['Kelly', 'Kelly', 'Kelly'])
kelly_classes

all_students_classes = students_classes.append(kelly_classes)

all_students_classes
```

and It give me error like this

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In\[35\], line 3
1 # Finally, we can append all of the data in this new Series to the first using the .append()
2 # function.
\----\> 3 all_students_classes.str = students_classes.append(kelly_classes)
5 # This creates a series which has our original people in it as well as all of Kelly's courses
6 all_students_classes

File \~\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python310\\site-packages\\pandas\\core\\generic.py:5989, in NDFrame.__getattr__(self, name)
5982 if (
5983     name not in self.\_internal_names_set
5984     and name not in self.\_metadata
5985     and name not in self.\_accessors
5986     and self.\_info_axis.\_can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name)
5987 ):
5988     return self\[name\]
\-\> 5989 return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'append'
```

[I expect something like this from the e-learning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4W3c3.png)

Comment: Did you look up the official `pandas` documentation? Does the `Series` have a `append` method?  Also what version is your `pandas`?

Comment: It seems that the append method has been removed. In my colab version, there is a warning that says *The series.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead*  In my conda version, it is unusable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In relatively recent pandas version, 1.5.2, `append` works, but gives a warning.

In pd 2.0, `append` has been removed

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/whatsnew/v2.0.0.html#deprecations

```
In [14]: students_classes = pd.Series({'Alice': 'Physics',
    ...:                    'Jack': 'Chemistry',
    ...:                    'Molly': 'English',
    ...:                    'Sam': 'History'})
    ...: kelly_classes = pd.Series(['Philosophy', 'Arts', 'Math'], index=['Kelly', 'Kelly', 'Kelly'])

In [15]: students_classes.append(kelly_classes)
C:\Users\paul\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_6072\990183765.py:1: FutureWarning: The series.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
  students_classes.append(kelly_classes)
Out[15]: 
Alice       Physics
Jack      Chemistry
Molly       English
Sam         History
Kelly    Philosophy
Kelly          Arts
Kelly          Math
dtype: object
```

Under the covers, `append` method uses `_append`, which works without raising the warning:

```
In [16]: students_classes._append(kelly_classes)
Out[16]: 
Alice       Physics
Jack      Chemistry
Molly       English
Sam         History
Kelly    Philosophy
Kelly          Arts
Kelly          Math
dtype: object
```

And using the recommended `concat`:

```
In [18]: pd.concat([students_classes,kelly_classes])
Out[18]: 
Alice       Physics
Jack      Chemistry
Molly       English
Sam         History
Kelly    Philosophy
Kelly          Arts
Kelly          Math
dtype: object
```

Python `lists` have an efficient `append` method.  `numpy` has a `np.append` function which is a poorly named cover for calling `np.concatenate`, and is often misused (it shouldn't be used iteratively).  `pandas` may be trying to avoid similar problems by getting rid of the `append` method.  With `pd.concat` you can join many Series (or frames) at once, and aren't (as) tempted to use it in a loop.

Looking up the code for `_append` (which is still in 2.0), I see it ends up using `pd.concat`.  So there's no value in using this 'work-around'.  Use `concat` as recommended.

Comment: Thank you! Also thank you for your recommendation!!! will try to use concat for future

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and it throws the same error as the original.  I am using Pandas 2.0.1.  Instead of the error "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'concat'", it throws "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'concat'

Comment: No, read the docs.  `pd.concat([df1, df2,...])`.  It's a **function**, not a `method`!

Comment: FYI, using `pd.concat` results in TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid. 

I had to cast my string as a Series to add using `pd.Series()`

Answer (score 3):

Probably an update of pandas may have changed the syntax, but you probably are looking for:

```
all_students_classes = students_classes._append(kelly_classes)
```

(quick tip, you can check the class definition in VS code by right cliking on the pd.Series and choosing Go to Definition, then you can see some of the methods defined at least). Otherwise use the `concat` method that uses this.

Comment: I don't think it's advisable to recommend a private function, especially when the correct ".append()" gives the user fair warning that the method call will be removed from pandas 2.0 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

When the append method cannot be replaced due to configured environment restrictions, I recommend you to use _append